# How do i select a number in a matrix in c?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

So I have made a matrix, that's formed by (NxN). And the numbers for the matrix are put in through user input into a multidimensional array. I'm using pointers and malloc. So I have to select a number in the array to then get the sum of adjacent numbers, the number is selected just by saying the position. So just saying the 3rd number in the matrix. I am a little confused on how to just select a number, I have a general idea of incrementing to get to the right position? Would this be right? And will this then make it harder or easier to then get the sum of the adjacent numbers?

Just a little confused on how to then do this with a multidimensional array, would i just turn it back into a single array?
This is how i create the matrix:

```
for(i = 0; i< matrixSize; i++)
{ 
    for(j=0; j < matrixSize; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &matrixValues[i][j]); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: The 3rd number in the matrix? what does that mean? What column and what row would that be? and why didn't you post your code?

Comment: If you have what you need in a normal array could you then explain how that works a little bit more?

Comment: The user says they want to find the largest sum for the 5th number in the matrix so say its 25. Then you find the adjacent numbers, to find the largest sum that includes 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean number in a matrix as follows (example for matrixSize == 4):

```
  0  1  2  3
  4  5  6  7
  8  9 10 11
 12 13 14 15
```

you can just calculate indexes from `number`

```
 matrixValues[number/matrixSize][number%matrixSize]
```

**EDIT:**

For case when your 2D arreay defined as

```
 int matrixValues[matrixSize][matrixSize];
```

All elements allocated in memory sequentially, i.e. element `matrixValues[1][0]` is exact after `matrixValues[0][matrixSize-1]`, so you can use `number` as shift from adress of element `matrixValues[0][0]`, e.g.:

```
 *(((int*)matrixValues) + number)
```

For your example it can be

```cpp
    int matrixValues[matrixSize][matrixSize];
    // input as 2D array
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i< matrixSize; i++)
    { 
        for(j=0; j < matrixSize; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrixValues[i][j]); 
        }   
    }   
    // using address of matrix as begining of array
    int* fakeArray = (int*)matrixValues;
    // output as 1D arrray
    int n;
    for(n = 0; n < matrixSize * matrixSize ; n++)
    {
        printf("%d ", fakeArray[n]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. Would i not want n to be compared to the input number? For example if i wanted 5 from your example. I would input 5. Then it would cycle through till the 5th number? Sorry I may not be understanding.

Comment: For better understanding you can explain how your program should work. What is input? If you want first 5 elements, ask `N` with other `scanf("%d",&N);` (for example N will be 5) and make loop `for (n = 0; n < N; n++)` for output

Comment: 3 2
21 22 23
20 00 11
17 06 15    This would be the input for example, 3 would be the size so (3x3), 2 would be the selection of the number, so 22 in this instance. You then work out the sum of the adjacent numbers. So 22+21 for example. If this clears up what i'm trying to do?

Comment: The first number (3) is a size, the second (2) is a number from the beginning, that should be sum to result. The input is from keyboard?

Comment: I think you can work with simple array (not matrix). Why do you use 2D array?

Comment: Needs to be a matrix, as it will be reading it as a matrix. But yes from the input of a keyboard. For the adjacent numbers as well, it needs to read the numbers diagonally, the number on its left, the number on its right, the number above and the number below it.

Comment: Try to write the whole program using step-by-step approach. Read ask size, then ask N, then ask numbers, and perform the calculation. I hope you already know everything you need. If you have troubles, update you initial question text by adding new code and issue clarification. And write comments to your code

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. Just the calculation i have trouble with, you have made it a bit clearer now which is a great help.